# How can I refresh fullcalendar after insert a row in mysql without refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

my problem is that I do an ajax petition to insert a event to mysql, so if everything is ok I wanted to refresh (refetch events) fullcalendar to see the new insert without refresh page. Besides, I am using TimeGrid View and version 4 of the plugin.

I tested:

```
calendar.refetch();
calendar.refetchEvents();
$('calendar').fullcalendar('rerenderEvents');
$('calendar').fullcalendar('refetchEvents');
```

but that does not work, at least in v4.

Calendar Code:

```
var calendar;
/* Calendario JS */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'bootstrap' ],
      defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      locale: 'es',
      minTime: "07:00:00",
      maxTime: "23:00:00",
      header: {
          left: 'title', //today, prev, next
          center: 'BtnAñadirReserva',
          right: 'today, prev,next' //month, basicWeek, basicDay, gendaWeek, agendaDay
      },
      customButtons: {
          BtnAñadirReserva: {
              text: "Añadir Reserva",
              bootstrapFontAwesome: "fa-calendar-plus Añadir Reserva",
              click: function(){
                showNoti();
              }
          }
      },
      events: {
        url: url_controller,
        method: 'post',
        extraParams: {
          accio: "getReservas"
        },
        failure: function() {
          alert('Hubo un error recorriendo las reservas!');
        },
        color: 'blue',   // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'white' // a non-ajax option
      },
      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        getInfoByID(calEvent.event.id);
      }
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: url_controller,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
         accio: "insertReserva",
         params: json
     },
     beforeSend: function () {},
     success: function(result){
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(result); 
        if(status == true){
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
           //calendar.refetch();
           //calendar.refetchEvents();
           //$('calendar').fullcalendar('rerenderEvents');
           //$('calendar').fullcalendar('refetchEvents');
        } else {
           /* Error sql php */
        }
      },
     error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        /* Error ajax petition */
     }
});
```

No errors showed in console/network if I use .fullcalendar but with .refetch it says that it does not a function.
Is not a php problem because I can insert properly and if I refresh page I can see the new event that I added.

Comment: I think I ended up with this kind of issues using `$element.fullCalendar('destroy');` then `$element.fullCalendar({opts});`

Comment: What result did you get when you tested? Console errors, perhaps? If so please tell us. Also it would help to show your calendar code. `calendar.refetchEvents();` should work in v4, assuming that a) that's the name of the variable you created to hold the calendar reference, and b) that variable is in scope when you try to use it. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents

Comment: The other option, once you've sent the new event to the server, is to add it directly to the calendar using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent . Then you don't actually need to refetch all the data from the server just to see one more event

Comment: @Adyson I updated the post with calendar code. I tried calendar.refectch() calendar.refetchEvents(); but it does nothing, and no errors in console.

Comment: @enguerranws I am going to try this afternoon. Thanks.

Comment: And you don't see any Ajax request being triggered in your network tools when you run refetchEvents()? I don't understand how calendar.refectch()  is not producing an error though...there is no such method available on the calendar object, it should produce a crash. Are you sure that code is even being executed?

Comment: @ADyson I resolved the problem. With `refectch()` it does not found the function but with `refetchEvents()`` it works correctly. There were a problem with the `if`... Sorry and Thanks!